# setting up DPM performance level permanently

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde, amdgpu

I have Kubuntu 20.04 with AsRock Radeon RX 5500 XT Challenger graphics. I have two monitors (both 1920x1080), primary one having 75Hz (HDMI) and secondary 60Hz (DisplayPort).

Now I see a flickering on the primary monitor. When I change the frequency to 60Hz the flickering dissapears. After some googling I've found that setting `low` or `high` into the `/sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level` might do the trick. And it seems it really does. But I need to do this manually every time i reboot. Is there some way how can i set this parameter permanently?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, I created `/etc/rc.local` file, made it executable (`chmod a+x /etc/rc.local`) and enabled the systemd service to run this script as described here: [how to enable rc.local with systemd](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd).
This is the content of the rc.local file:

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level
```

It seems it's working now without any flickering